# Unable to get skills from Linkedin API using Scribe

Tags: java, linkedin-api, scribe

I'm trying to get skills information from LinkedIn using Scribe library.

Everything works. But it can not print out the skills in either XML or JSON format.

I checked the URL: https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,skills) in apigee.  It works fine.  So I'm wondering what's wrong in code.

Here is the code:

```
public class LinkedInExample {
   private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,skills)";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
                             .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
                             .apiKey("KEY")
                             .apiSecret("SECRET")
                             .build();
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Obtain the Request Token
      Token requestToken = service.getRequestToken();

      System.out.println(service.getAuthorizationUrl(requestToken));
      System.out.println("And paste the verifier here");
      System.out.print(">>");
      Verifier verifier = new Verifier(in.nextLine());

      // Trade the Request Token and Verfier for the Access Token
      System.out.println("Trading the Request Token for an Access Token");
      Token accessToken = service.getAccessToken(requestToken, verifier);
      System.out.println("Got the Access Token!");

      // Now let's go and ask for a protected resource!
      OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
      service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
      Response response = request.send();
      System.out.println(response.getBody());

   }
}
```

The output of this code is like:

```
{"id": "UU4glj53pm"}
```

The skills' information is missing.

Comment: what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: @mazaneicha I didn't get error.  It simply print out a blank {} for skills.  Other profile fields like id, last name are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just find that my application has to gain r_fullprofile member permission to be able to get skills information for LinkedIn API.  So there is nothing wrong in the code.